# Need to get a ServiceProvider Certificate

Tags: single-sign-on

I am working on Single-Sign-on concept using Federated Authentication Id from One Salesforce Org to another Org. In this concept where to be get the Service Provider Certificate at the time of creating the ServiceProvider in IdentityProvider Org. I get the Identity Provider Certificate but i didn't find out the Service Provider certificate. 
 Please let me give the solution for this concept.

Comment: Wouldn't this just be the cert from your SP org?